# Updating massive number of records -- performance optimization

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, optimization

I have a baseball tool that allows users to analyze a player's historical batting stats.  For example, how many hits does A-Rod have over the past 7 days during night-time conditions?  I want to expand the timeframe so a user can analyze a player's batting stats to as far back as 365 days. However, doing so requires some serious performance optimization.  Here are my current set of models:

```
class AtBat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :batter
  belongs_to :pitcher
  belongs_to :weather_condition

  ### DATA MODEL ###
  # id
  # batter_id
  # pitcher_id
  # weather_condition_id
  # hit (boolean)
  ##################
end

class BattingStat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :batter
  belongs_to :recordable, :polymorphic => true # e.g., Batter, Pitcher, WeatherCondition

  ### DATA MODEL ###
  # id
  # batter_id
  # recordable_id
  # recordable_type
  # hits7
  # outs7
  # at_bats7
  # batting_avg7
  # ...
  # hits365
  # outs365
  # at_bats365
  # batting_avg365
  ##################
end

class Batter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :batting_stats, :as => :recordable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :at_bats, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Pitcher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :batting_stats, :as => :recordable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :at_bats, :dependent => :destroy
end

class WeatherCondition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :batting_stats, :as => :recordable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :at_bats, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

For the sake of keeping my question at a reasonable length, let me narrate what I am doing to update the batting_stats table instead of copying a bunch of code.  Let's start with 7 days.

1. Retrieve all the at_bat records over the past 7 days.
2. Iterate over each at_bat record…
3. Given an at_bat record, grab the associated batter and associated weather_condition, find the correct batting_stat record (BattingStat.find_or_create_by_batter_and_recordable(batter, weather_condition), then update the batting_stat record.
4. Repeat Step 3 for batter and pitcher (recordables).

Steps 1-4 are repeated for other time periods as well -- 15 days, 30 days, etc.

Now I imagine how laborious this would be to run a script every day to make these updates if I were to expand the time periods from a mangeable 7/15/30 to 7/15/30/45/60/90/180/365.

So my question is how would you approach getting this to run at the highest levels of performance?

Comment: I've built a similar system for a golf app. I'm willing to share but it requires a pretty extensive explanation. Are you willing to alter your architecture or are you just looking for a way to optimize the architecture you currently have?

Comment: I'd be very appreciated to hear how you did it.  Willing to update arch, but prob down the road.

Comment: How many records are you dealing with? There can't be that many data points for baseball, surely (hundreds of thousands?). Can't you just hold the lot in memory, possibly sliced by player into a map if need be, and calculate it all on the fly?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can port it to MySQL, but for PostgreSQL you would do something like http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views (you should definitely try to use the database directly, so consider asking your question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AR isn't really meant to do bulk processing like this.  You're probably better off doing your batch updates by dropping into SQL proper and doing an `INSERT FROM SELECT` (or perhaps using a gem that did this for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to store the data in such a way that you can lop off the the last day and replace it with a new first day in such away that you don't have to recompute the total.

One way of doing this would be to store the previous value of the addition and subtract the last day value from it and then add the new day value and then divide by 15/30/90/365 whatever.

That turns 366 operations into 3. Now is reading from the database slower than 363 operations?

This also saves you on the iterations, so all you need to do is check each day which of the weather conditions need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with batch loading of 600,000 records of US rental data each week. To process each record serially would take over 24 hours. But it wasn't necessarily the database that was the bottleneck - although each insertion took a fixed amount of time, the database was not maxxed/pegged/flatlined by the activity.

I knew that splitting a file into individual string records was easy and fast. In our case, the input file was in the form of XML, and I used a simple Java StringTokenizer to split the file on the ... tags.

That quickly gave me a large array of XML snippets containing the rental property information that I needed to parse and import.

I then used the Java ThreadPoolExecutor/FutureTask/Callable convention to create a pool of 20 threads that would take each XML snippet as input, extract the relevant data and perform the database inserts. I don't know what your architecture's equivalent would be, but I'm guessing there is something similar.

In the end, I was able to adjust the size of the threadpool to maximize record throughput by monitoring the database server load under different test conditions. We settled on a threadpool size of 25.

Answer (score 0):

When I have had to this kind of work before, I bust out my SQL references and refresh my mind with how to do complex updates. Usually you can do a lot of updating in short fashion with a good query. Also, you should be able to find direct assistance with the query (post your schema and starting queries in a gist if they are really huge)

I had to seed a counter_cache value recently, and before doing it as a bunch of ruby code loading the parents and counting their children, I gave this query a shot:

```
UPDATE rates r SET children_count = child_counts.my_count from (SELECT parent_id, count(*) as my_count FROM rates GROUP BY parent_id having parent_id is not null) as child_counts where child_counts.parent_id = r.id;
```

which updated 200k rows in just a few secs

If you can't do it in one query, and if its a one time operation, you can break your process into 2 steps. First do the heavy lifting and store the results in a new table, then read from that table and do the final update. I had to do some massive data aggregation recently, and all the heavy lifting took 2 days of processing and calculations. The result was put into a new table with a related row id and final total. In production then I just had a quick script that read from that new table and updated the related rows. This also allowed me to stop and restart from where I had left off, and pre-check the results before the prod update. Also, it made the prod update really fast.

While doing this, I also learned that its important to do your work in batches if you can, and commit the transaction as often as possible/safe, so you aren't holding on to to a large transaction for too long.